# Symfony 2 Forward Request passing along GET/POST params

Tags: php, symfony, forwarding

Is it possible to forward a request, passing along all GET/POST params?

I think if I just do

```
$this->forward('dest')
```

I will go to `dest` without any GET/POST params?

**UPDATE**

My objective is actually to have a controller action like `addSomething` that takes checks that the user has the sufficient "items" to add something. Then forward the request to the approperiate controller to continue the actual adding of adding{Type}Something

Or would getting a "checking" service in all controllers that does the checking be more appropriate? Anyways, I think its informative to know how to forward to a controller action with all params

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see any reason here to forward the request back through the kernel. You can go the route of encapsulating this logic in a checker service, as you've suggested, or you may be able to create a `kernel.request` listener that runs after the router listener and applies the `_controller` attribute only if your conditions are met.

For example, this `routing.yml`:

```
some_route:
    pattern:  /xyz
    defaults: { _controller_candidate: "FooBundle:Bar:baz" }
```

And this listener:

```
class MyListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest($event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller_candidiate')) {
            return;
        }

        if (/* your logic... */) {
            $request->attributes->set('_controller', $controller');
        }
    }
}
```

Configured to run *after* the core router listener:

```
services:
    my_listener:
        class: MyListener
        tags:
            -
                name:     kernel.event_listener
                event:    kernel.request
                priority: -10
```

The priority of the core router listener is `0` in Symfony 2.0 and `32` in Symfony 2.1. In either case, a priority of `-10` should work.

I'm curious to see if this works :)

Comment: That looks like it works. Will update whether it works after I try that later. If I want to do the reverse, run something after a controller action, is there a similar event? How do you find out about these seemingly undocumented methods?

Comment: Ok, I found my answer http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#handling-requests. Wonder which is the right method to use? `kernel.response`?

Comment: Oh I use `@Route` annotation, how can I modify `$request->attributes->get('_controller_candidiate')`?

Comment: This is not possible with the `@Route` annotation.

Comment: Ok I used `$req->attributes->get('_route')` instead

Answer (score 31):

Easiest solution (and one I'd probably go for) would be to just pass Request class as forward parameter

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    return $this->forward('AcmeBundle:Forward:new', array('request' => $request));
}
```

And in forwarded action just use it as method param:

```
public function testAction($request)
{
    var_dump($request);exit;
}
```

Comment: BUT... there might be a problem when playing with forms - if both action (the 'forwarding' and the 'forwarded to') have forms with submissions, You will fall into a trap - the 'forwarded to' action sees the $_POST form from the previous controller, so it crashes on CSRF Token (invalid, from the previous form.

Comment: @thorinkor Is there a valid way around it? Regenerating it somehow? I tried with service security.csrf.token_manager and getToken() but no luck.

Comment: @userfuser the best solution - avoid it :) Maybe You could try to get it from 1st form request and resend it in forwarding method?

Answer (score 15):

All POST param are automatically forwarded. No action is needed to have POST param in the target controller.
But you have to explicitly pass query (GET) params and path params. The forward method take 2 optionals parameter representing respectively the pathParam and the queryParam arrays. You can just pass all the query param from the current request

```
public testAction(Request $request){
    $pathParam = array(); //Specified path param if you have some
    $queryParam = $request->query->all(); 
    $response = $this->forward("AcmeBundle:Forward:new", $pathParam, $queryParam);
}
```

Comment: best answer to original question

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding "request attributes" as "path" works for me:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $path = $this->getRequest()->attributes->all();
    return $this->forward('CompMyBundle:MyController:MyAction', $path);
}
```

$path['_controller'] will be overwritten in forward() method!