# Symfony2 why does forward nest request objects?

Tags: symfony, httpresponse, forwarding

When I do a forward() in a controller, I lose my route and route_parameters.

When I have ParentAction, that does a forward to ChildAction. In Childaction I do `return $this->render('myTemplate.html.twig', array());` then the request attributes get nested!

So when the template gets rendered, instead of `$request['attributes']['_route_parameters']` I get `$request['attributes']['request']['attributes']['_route_parameters']`.

Although in ChildAction, when I do a `$this->getRequest();` the hierarchie is normal.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that symfony doesn't assume you have the same route parameters.
So when you forward you need to re-supply the route parameters required by the new route even if they are the same.

(Incidentally you must also provide any query parameters for the new route.)

```
public function indexAction($param)
{

    return $this->forward(
        'AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::otherAction',
        array("someOtherParam" => $param),
        $request->query->all() // Causes query string params to be copied
    );
}

// This route has a different parameter.
public function otherAction($someOtherParam) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to pass your Request as second parameter when forwarding.

```
$response = $this->forward('MyBundle:MyController:myAction', array('request' => $request));
```

Also, as forward is just a shortcut for core Symfony2 functionality, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707586/symfony-2-forward-request-passing-along-get-post-params) may probably help.

Comment: Can you check my edit ? I can read the request and such but there is something weird going on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code helped:

```
$subRequest = $this->container->get('request')->duplicate(
    array(), 
    null, 
    array('topicId' => $topicId,'_controller' => 'SomeBundle:Topic:close'));

return $this->container->get('http_kernel')
    ->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

"Topic" is TopicController and "close" is closeAction