# Symfony 3 forward GET parameters to another controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have Symfony 3.4 running a JSON API. All the responses from the API are formatted in JSON, and as such, I can't use the built-in Symfony debugger on the API controllers. I want to have an action that collects the JSON response from the API controller, then renders it inside of HTML so I can have access to the debugger for the request. I'd like to do something like this, but I can't seem to properly forward the GET parameters.

I tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707586/symfony-2-forward-request-passing-along-get-post-params) but didn't have any luck.

I'd like to send send requests to my controller like this:
`http://localhost/admin/my_api_route_name?access_token=abc123`

```
public function apiAction(Request $request, $path) {
    $params = $request->query->all();
    $fpath = $this->routeToControllerName($path);
    $response = $this->forward($fpath, [], $params);
    return $this->render('TestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', ["content" => $response->getContent()]);
}

private function routeToControllerName($routename) {
    $routes = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection();
    return $routes->get($routename)->getDefaults()['_controller'];
}
```

Comment: In the `dev` environment Symfony >= 2.4 provides the profile URL in your JSON header labeled `X-Debug-Token-Link`. Just use your browser to inspect the header or any other method you prefer to view headers with and you will find it. Then you won't have to mess around with forwarding the request.

Comment: Have you tried to pass as parameter a Request object with your get parameters in it to your controller when forwarding?

Comment: @hcoat I had no idea, that's quite helpful. I'll leave the question open since I'd still like to know how to accomplish the forwarding of parameters, but for now the debugger link is great!

Comment: @iiirxs Like this? `$this->forward($fpath, ['request' => $request]);`

Comment: Yes exactly like that

Comment: @iiirxs alas, that didn't work for me.