# POST-Params not accessible in Symfony Controller when forward is used?

Tags: symfony

I use the [forward-method](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html) to forward requests to another Controller action:

```
$response = $this->forward($menuItemConfig['controller'] . ':' . $actionParams['action'], [
    'request' => $request,
]);
```

This is the action of the Controller - post params are empty.

```
public function delete(Request $request): Response
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') == false) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Only POST allowed for this action.');
    }

    $postParams = $request->request->all();
    dump($postParams);
    die;
}
```

Passing parameters to the action does not work. All not-DI-params of the action are generally empty.

Symfony version 5.2.3

Comment: your code looks alright, have you tried to dump the `$request->request->all()` in the first method to be sure you've parameters in the first place ?

Comment: Pretty sure it is up to you to pass along parameters though to be honest I don't understand why.  Maybe try what the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707586/symfony-2-forward-request-passing-along-get-post-params) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are missing `:`, [try this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html):

```
$response = $this->forward($menuItemConfig['controller'] . '::' . $actionParams['action'], [
'request' => $request,]);
```

Comment: A single colon actually works just fine.  They would have gotten a route error message if it did not.  The double colon is actually a holdover from the early days when you had Bundle:Controller:Action mappings.  The docs still show two colons but again, a single one works just fine.